# setBackgroundColor covers element

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I have an NSWindow, and I'm using this code to add a bottom-metal-bar at the bottom.

```
[MyWindow setContentBorderThickness:40.0 forEdge:NSMinYEdge];
```

That works fine.  But, once I use this:

```
[MyWindow setBackgroundColor: [NSColor redColor]];
```

The red covers the bar at the bottom.  The bar shows correctly without the background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would appear that changing the background-color of an `NSWindow` negates its bottom border. In order to achieve both effects, you can do one of two things:

1. In Interface Builder, move all your interface elements to a subclass of `NSView` that draws its background and add the view to your window.
2. Create an `NSView` that emulates the bottom border of your window and set the window's background color.

Personally, I would go for the first option, because it requires less work (trying to emulate a bottom border will be difficult, even with `NSGradient`) , but both are a possibility.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I attempted to do instead was make an image that was the background color I wanted, and use a bit of resizing in IB to make it the background color of the window.

Comment: You can do that with either option, drawing the image as the background to the view.